# Crystal Reports Sort By Running Total

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

I've created few running totals using formulas as explained in the Crystal Reports Help. But when I try to Sort the report using my group running totals, it doesn't show me those formulas in the Sort Expert.

I think it's because I used `WhilePrintingRecord` in my formula as instructed in CR Help.

Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the RunningTotals are evaluated at the time of printing. The straight forward approach would be to create a stored procedure with view or SQL Expression. Use Top N/Group sort after that fields being added to the report.